# retrieve contents between parenthesis

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to retrieve the substring between the parenthesis (exclude the parenthesis):

I tried the following but it's returning the the value between the parenthesis along with the parenthesis. I would like to exclude the parentheses.

```
 a= "testing (EMI:30384)"
 a[/\(.*?\)/]   ***returns (EMI:30384)
```

Thanks for a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` capture between

`\(` and `\)` escape ()

```
\((.*)\)
```

will match EMI:30384

[image]

```
irb(main):005:0> a= "testing (EMI:30384)"
=> "testing (EMI:30384)"
irb(main):006:0> p a.match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]
"EMI:30384"
```

Comment: Hmm, that's really strange but am still getting the parenthesis :(

Comment: sorry I fixed the index it should be 1 not 0

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return a match group by using parenthesis in your expression, accessed with `\1`. More explanation here http://www.railsrocket.com/regular-expressions-in-ruby-and-rails

```
str = "testing (EMI:30384)"
ptrn = "/\((.*?)\)/"
str.gsub(ptrn, "\1")
```

Comment: It still includes the parenthesis

Comment: updated the code to better show how to access the matched group

Comment: You have to use matched groups

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions...using a.gsub(/[^(]+(/, '').gsub(/([^)]+))/, '\1') seems to do the job

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to capturing groups, you can use look behind and look ahead but it's probably too complicated for your usecase `a[/(?<=\().*(?=\))/]` gives exactly `EMI:30384`

Comment: Am getting : undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=\().*(?=\))/

Comment: have you tried substitution:
`a.gsub(/[^(]+\(/, '').gsub(/([^)]+)\)/, '\1')`

Comment: Pheww, using a.gsub(/[^(]+\(/, '').gsub(/([^)]+)\)/, '\1') seems to do the job

Comment: I don't know why it's not working when I make use of the previous solutions